# Node is jumping forward and backward on hover

Tags: javafx-8

This is my css

```
.my-node:hover
{
   -fx-translate-z:-50;
}
```

and I have perspective camera for the scence

`scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());`

Now when I move my cursor on the node with applied class it starts jumping forward and backward.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve?

If node changes z coordinates it will move back and forth **except** situation then node is located exactly in the place where z-axis is started.

Comment: I want to achieve a hover effect which hovered node move up or in other word comes closer to camera

Comment: do you really use 3D app or just want pseudo 3D effect?

Comment: I want a real 3D effect. and what do you mean by do i really use 3D app? I'm using Javafx to create my app.

Comment: UI software is full of pseudo-3D effects, e.g. every button is a simple plain image which is changed to another image on click, no 3D involved while images being crafted to look "three-dimensional". 3D applications is a whole another story, and much more complex one.

Comment: I want to create 3D application. but I can't figure out how to pick a node in 3D scene.

Comment: @Eeliya sweet code please - short, runnable, demonstrating your problem and nothing else :-)